# Generating combinations with repetetions in python

Tags: python, combinations, permutation, python-itertools

I generated combination of numbers, for example `123`, using this code

```
from itertools import combinations
for i in set(combinations('123',2)):
    print(''.join(i))
```

I get the desired output here

```
13
12
23
```

But when I use `133`, I get

```
13
33
```

But I want to ignore the repetition, I want the output as

```
13
13
33
```

Is there any alternate approach?

Comment: Remove the `set` call. That is what is reducing `13 13 33` to `13 33`

Comment: Well don't call `set()`? I don't see why you need to call `set()`.

Comment: Why do you use `set` if you do not want to remove repitition?

Comment: Yeah Thanks! how does set reduce it though ?

Comment: Because a set only stores **unique** values. You then iterate over the set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`set()`s by nature, don't allow any duplicate elements. **Each element in a** `set()` **must be unique**. The Python documentation makes note of this:

> Python also includes a data type for sets. A set is an unordered collection **with no duplicate elements**.

Emphasis mine. That is why your not getting your expected output. When you call `set()`, it removes the duplicate `13` from your combinations. Instead, just iterate through the combination object as is:

```
from itertools import combinations

for i in combinations('133', 2): # no call to set()
    print(''.join(i))
```

Which outputs:

```
13
13
33
```

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple. You should use list(combinations('123',2)) and not set. Set reduces identical values.

Comment: Or simply *no* `list(..)`, `tuple(..)`,... at all.

Comment: You're right. He can just remove the set, the for loop will iterate properly.

Comment: There is **no need** to call `list()`. In fact, you want to avoid that altogether if all you do is loop.